# Is SATA-2 backwards compatible with SATA-1?

Tags: sata, hard-drive

As per the title, are the two versions compatible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The designers of SATA intended for **backwards** and **forwards** compatibility, however, there are some SATA 1 controllers that don't support SATA 2 drives. For this reason, some HD manufacturers added a SATA1/2 mode jumper so that the drives would work with the affected controllers.

See this section of the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#SATA_1.5_Gbit.2Fs_and_SATA_3_Gbit.2Fs) for relevant chipset info. From that section, affected chipsets are motherboard host controllers using the VIA and SIS chipsets VT8237, VT8237R, VT6420, VT6421L, SIS760, SIS964 found on the ECS 755-A2 manufactured in 2003.

You should be ok using SATA 1 drives with SATA 2 controllers. (At least, I didn't find any contradictory information).

Comment: You're right on this. Any SATA2 controller support SATA1 device with no problem and same thing for sata1 controller with sata2 device, except for those named above.

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is. Sometime you may need to put a jumper on a SATA2 harddrive to make it work on SATA 1 controller but you rarely need it as the harddrive ajust himself according to what is available.