# SATA3 and backwards compatability

Tags: sata, hardware

Hay guys, I'm making a NAS for serving my files around my network. I bought a motherboard, a MSI KM4M-V Micro ATX. the spec says that it has "2 SATA 1.5Gb/s connectors". I'm however find these drives quite expensive. Would a SATA3 based drive work on this motherboard?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SATA 3 drives are backwards compatible with 1.5Gbps controllers.  Naturally the speed will be limited to the 1.5Gbps of the controller

Answer (score 0):

You may get enough relevant information here:
[Is SATA 2 backwards compatible with SATA 1](https://serverfault.com/questions/6428/is-sata-2-backwards-compatible-with-sata-1)

The newer SATA drives will work, but you may have to set a jumper if you get an unlucky board/drive combination.

Comment: thanks, the drive im thinking of getting is a WD1002FBYS. any ideas if this will work?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with drive specifics enough to tell you. The WD drive may have a "sata 1 mode" jumper or something similar; you should familiarize yourself with its location. You may not need to set it, though.

Answer (score 0):

At work we use WD SATA2 drives on boards that only have SATA1. I would look to see if it has four jumpers aligned like this : : : : and then you'll want to put a jumper on the second set from the left like this : [:] : : ... that is all we do at work and it fixes the problem.